# Recommendation for Automated Deployment tools for Windows Environment?

Tags: deployment, automation, windows-server

As a .NET programmer, I create Windows Services and Web Applications.

These are deployed on a staging environment and then, after regression tests are successful, they are deployed on a production environment.

Although it looks more like an IT related question, I think that when a version changes, for instance, it's only the programmer who actually knows the impact of the new version, and which service should be taken offline in order to change its DLLs, then taking it online again (just an example).

So I think that it's the programmer's job to create some kind of an automated script (or something) to be executed on each target machine.

Do you happen to know such a framework for Windows Server 2003/2008 machines?

My requirements for such framework are:

- Human readable script (or anything else which is textual, such as XML)
- Can detect a service by its name and start/stop it
- Can detect a web application installed on IIS and start/stop it
- Copy/Create/Move/Delete/Compress/Decompress files and folders
- Can send emails

Do you happen to know such a framework for Windows Server 2003/2008 machines?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I found that a PowerShell script can be helpful to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good practice to use native tool on each platform.

In Windows it's a Windows Installer, and based on it - Wix and InstallShield.
We use Wix in our company for many projects, and deployment of both client and server components.

It's XML based (as you asked) and quite simple to start using immediately.

Some concepts are tricky to understand, but then you get tons of information in Internet, and once you've done something, you'll never forget.